# Is it possible to modify libvirt virtual machine network related configuration without restarting the VM?

Tags: libvirt, virsh

Let's say, that I have a virtual machine named `test` with following configuration:

```
$ virsh dumpxml test
<domain type='kvm' id='42'>
  <name>test</name>
  <uuid>4b72f3be-41f5-41ec-8149-647ab73d92f7</uuid>
  /* output removed for brevity */
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:fb:3f:85'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <target dev='vnet23'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:94:7d:c8'/>
      <source bridge='br2'/>
      <target dev='vnet24'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
  /* output removed for brevity */
  </devices>
</domain>

$
```

Now I edit the configuration with `virsh edit test` and associate the `vnet24` with `br3` instead of `br2`. Is it possible to apply those changes without restarting the virtual machine? Obviously, one option is to set this manually with `ip` or `brctl` utility, but maybe it's somehow possible with `virsh` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file update.xml

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:94:7d:c8'/>
  <source bridge='br3'/>
  <target dev='vnet24'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net2'/>
</interface>
```

You can do

```
sudo virsh update-device test update.xml --persistent
```

Notice that I omitted `<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>` from update.xml because if I don't for some reason I can't add --persistent flag. --persistent flag equals --live (to apply to a running domain) --config (to affect next startup)

Source: https://www.libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#update-device

Also interesting attach-interface command which lets you add a new interface on the fly (https://www.libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#attach-interface)